# is it acceptable to provide an API that is undefined a large part of the time?

Tags: api, inheritance, undefined

Given some type as follows:

```
class Thing {
  getInfo();
  isRemoteThing();
  getRemoteLocation();
}
```

The `getRemoteLocation()` method only has a defined result if `isRemoteThing()` returns true. Given that most `Thing`s are not remote, is this an acceptable API? The other option I see is to provide a `RemoteThing` subclass, but then the user needs a way to cast a `Thing` to a `RemoteThing` if necessary, which just seems to add a level of indirection to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Having an interface include members which are usable on some objects that implement the interface but not all of them, and also includes a query method to say which interface members will be useful, is a good pattern in cases where something is gained by it.

Examples of reasons where it can be useful:

- If it's likely than an interface member will be useful on some objects but not other instances *of the same type*, this pattern may be the only one that makes sense.
- If it's likely that a consumer may hold references to a variety of objects implementing the interface, some of which support a particular member and some of which do not, and if it's likely that someone with such a collection would want to use the member on those instances which support it, such usage will be more convenient if all objects implement an interface including the member, than if some do and some don't.  This is *especially* true for interface members like `IDisposable.Dispose` whose purpose is to notify the implementation of something it may or may not care about (e.g. that nobody needs it anymore and it may be abandoned without further notice), and ask it to do whatever it needs to as a consequence (in many cases nothing).  Blindly calling `Dispose` on an `IEnumerable<T>` is faster than checking whether an implementation of `IEnumerable` also implements `IDisposable`.  Not only the unconditional call faster than checking for `IDisposable` and then calling it--it's faster than checking whether an object implements `IDisposable` and finding out that it doesn't.
- In some cases, a consumer may use a field to hold different kinds of things at different times.  As an example, it may be useful to have a field which at some times will hold the only extant reference to a mutable object, and at other times will hold a possibly-shared reference to an immutable object.  If the type of the field includes mutating methods (which may or may not work) as well as a means of creating a new mutable instance with data copied from an immutable one, code which receives an object and might want to mutate the data can store a reference to the passed-in object.  If and when it wants to mutate the data, it can overwrite the field with a reference to a mutable copy; if it never ends up having to mutate the data, however, it can simply use the passed-in immutable object and never bother copying it.

The biggest disadvantage of having interfaces include members that aren't always useful is that it imposes more work on the implementers.  Thus, people writing interfaces should only include members whose existence could significantly benefit at least some consumers of almost every class implementing the interface.

Comment: It's a good effort at an answer, so I'll award the bounty, but I don't find this complete enough to choose it as an answer. To your first bullet, you do not consider moving the API to a subclass/subinterface as I suggest in the question. Your second bullet point is irrelevant, as the IDisposable interface is not optional in the slightest, whereas I am considering an interface which can be considered, to some degree, optional. If something is IDisposable it is 99.999% of the time known at compile time. I am considering the case where it is known only at runtime, which is a different problem.

Comment: @sooniln: The relationship between `IDisposable` and enumeration interfaces doesn't perfectly fit the point I was trying to make, but it's a well-known part of the Framework that actually exists.  Whether or not the object returned from the (non-generic) `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` method will implement `IDisposable` *cannot generally be known until run-time*. If one wants to imagine an optional hypothetical interface feature, how about imagining the convenience of having `IEnumerable` include a `Count` member, perhaps with an argument that would allow...

Comment: ...for options such as "return the count if convenient, -1 if not convenient, -2 for a sequence that may be over 2^31 items, or -3 if boundless", or "return count if bounded below 2^31, or throw otherwise".  Not all implementations of `IEnumerable` could have done anything useful with that method, and many might defer to a static `int ManuallyCountEnumerable(IEnumerable)` method, but the situation would have still been better than exists with the `IEnumerable.Count()` static method.

Comment: Ok, sure I like the the Count member example better, but the question is not so much whether the Count is useful (obviously it is, this information is needed somewhere) but what the appropriate way of defining the API is. As an optional API with some way of know if it is appropriate to call Count and what kind of result is returned? Or within a subclass (ICountableEnumerable or something)?

Comment: @sooniln: If I were designing a framework, I'd say that in many cases the right approach is to do "both": have a base `IEnumerable` which includes "optional" methods but does not specify that implementations need to do anything useful beyond basic enumeration *and the methods or properties necessary to describe capabilities*, but in addition to that I would also define some interface types like `ICountableEnumerable` and `IReadonlyImmutable`, and `IImmutableEnumerable` which wouldn't add new members but would specify that legitimate implementations must meet certain criteria.

Comment: @sooniln: In some cases it may be helpful for an object to receive an arbitrary `IEnumerable<T>` and decide at run-time whether to store a reference or copy it to a new collection.  In other cases, it could be more helpful for a routine to take a parameter of type `IImmutableEnumerable<T>`, thus freeing it from such concerns.  Of course, the actual `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't include anything that indicates whether an implementation can be safely regarded as immutable, but such a feature could have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Why should this not be acceptable? It should, however, be clearly documented. If you look at the .net class libraries or the JDK, there are collection interfaces defining methods to add or delete items, but there are unmodifiable classes implementing these interfaces. It is a good idea in this case - as you did - to provide a method to query the object if it has some capabilities, as this helps you avoid exceptions in the case that the method is not appropriate.

OTOH, if this is an API, it might be more appropriate to use an `interface` than a `class`.

Comment: There are collection interfaces with add() or remove() methods because these are operations every collection MUST consider. Some collections may consciously choose not to support them, but must give them consideration. This is also why it would be inappropriate to have something like a canAdd() method on a collections interface. In contrast, in my example, a Thing cannot even consider the question of remoteness, as this is not central to the idea of 'Thing-ness'. It only becomes relevant at the level of 'remote Thing-ness', so the collections libraries you mention are not a relevant example.